# FrontRow tutorial for Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I was wondering if there was a basic tutorial to get me started on coding a FrontRow plug-in / add-on using Xcode.
I searched Google a couple of times, but I haven't found a tutorial on this subject so far.

Answer (score 0):

After some more searching, I found [this Wiki-page](http://wiki.awkwardtv.org/wiki/FRAppliance_101) about creating an app for the Apple TV.
As far as I can tell now, it's a good base to start a FrontRow app too.
If someone else may find a better tutorial, please let me know.

http://wiki.awkwardtv.org/wiki/FRAppliance_101

**Edit:**
Doesn't really seem to work on my system.